# Nullable DateTime in Left Outer Join

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, linq-to-sql, left-join

I am trying to perform a Left Outer Join between 3 tables. However, when creating the output, the NullReferenceException occurs.

I've tried a couple options below by checking if the date is null and casting the datetime to a nullable value.

How do you perform a Left Outer Join on DateTime columns?

```
var query = from t1 in A
    join t2 in B
    on t1.newAsset equals t2.newAsset into grp1
    join t3 in C
    on t1.newAsset equals t3.newAsset into grp2
    from t2 in grp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from t3 in grp2.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        asset = t1.newAsset,
        standbyIssuedBeforeTarget = t1.issueDate
        standbyReturnedBeforeTarget = (DateTime?)t2.issueDate // Tried casting to a nullable date
        //standbyReturnedDuringTarget = (t3.issueDate == null ? SqlDateTime.Null : t3.issueDate) // Tried comparing issueDate to null
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where a `t1` row in A does not match any row in B, an outer join creates an output with `t1` but `t2` is null.
Then `t2.issueDate` will throw a `NullReferenceException`.
You can write something like this prior to c#6:

```
standbyReturnedBeforeTarget = t2 == null ? (DateTime?)null : t2.issueDate
```

And in C#6:

```
standbyReturnedBeforeTarget = t2?.issueDate
```